# Running script with java classpath

Tags: java, linux, bash, classpath

I am working in Debian Stable Linux. I am trying to use a script so that I do not have to type `-cp /home/auser/bin/` every time I use class file kept in a separate folder.

I have created a script file and kept it in path:

```
$ which japp.sh
/home/auser/bin/japp.sh
```

This script contains:

```
#! /bin/bash
# -cp for classpath: 
java -cp /home/auser/bin/ Jmyclass $1 $2 $3
```

`Jmyclass.class` is also there in `/home/auser/bin/` directory.

However, when I give command:

```
$ japp.sh first second third_arg
```

I get an error (from `Jmyclass`) indicating that are arguments are not being received by `Jmyclass`.

```
USAGE: java Jmyclass <d1name> <d2name> <mode>
```

Where is the problem and how can I correct it? Thanks for your help.

---

Edit: I just realized that the script does not work if argument 1 and/or 2 has spaces in them, even though I enclose them in double quotes:

```
japp.sh "first arg" "second arg" third_arg
```

How can this be corrected?

Comment: What do you get if you replace line three with `echo "java -cp /home/auser/bin/ Jmyclass $1 $2 $3"`?

Comment: It shows proper command with all 3 arguments in place. I just realized that the script does not work if argument(s) have spaces in them, even though I enclose them in double quotes ("first arg").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes that you use when calling the script are not included in the arguments. The argument is the the part inside the quotes. To fix this, You can add quotes in the script itself.

```
#! /bin/bash
# -cp for classpath: 
java -cp /home/auser/bin/ Jmyclass "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

Note that you'll still need to double-quote arguments with spaces when you call the script, to prevent them from being broken up.